# How do I delete a svn repository?

Tags: svn, debian-lenny

So, I created a repository like so: `svnadmin create /path/to/repository`

What's the equivalent for deleting? I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since a repository is not a single file but a directory structure (conf, dav, db, ...) you might want to use

```
rm -rf /path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 3):

`rm -rf /path/to/repository`